# Mutt: Saving a draft with attachment

Tags: mutt

I have been wondering if it is possible to save a draft that contains an attachment, so that I don't have to attach the file again when I reopen the mail with another mail-client. Is it possible that the attachment is also pushed to the mail server? (In the case of imap)

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Postponing a message preserves attachments. If that doesn’t work for you, what version are you using and how exactly are you creating the draft?

Comment: @phg comment is correct answer

Comment: That's right. I apologize. I modified the question.